# How to debug Core Data validation error code zero (0)?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When I call save on the Core Data managed object context while running the application in the simulator (iOS 5.1.1, XCode 4.4.1) I get two of the following validation errors:

```
Error Domain=CollectionItemError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CollectionItemError error 0.)"
```

Since there is an error code of zero (0) I'm not sure how to debug the problem. Suggestions?

Comment: Is this all you see for the error? Is there not more info above?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is all the information provided in the error object after the call to the save method.